# OKTA SCIM User custom attributes

Tags: okta, okta-api, scim, scim2

How can I pass **Company Name** value from Account/Settings pass as custom attribute to my SCIM Server?

Is there any way to access to **Company Name** value?

Answer (score 1):

Okta supports SCIM, and the ability to provision Users to external Identity Server (or applications) that support SCIM.

There are two ways to do this, you can use an on-premise agent (provided by Okta), which sends SCIM events from inside your network, or Okta can send SCIM events directly from the Service. You will have to ask support to turn on this feature.

In Okta, there is a directory (The Universal Directory), you an push any attribute that exists from that directory UD, to the SCIM service.

I know this is very high level, but it can be done.

It is not uncommon for companies to have a legacy IDM system like Oracle/Sun or even Microsoft, and have Okta send SCIM provisioning events to those systems.

Good Luck

https://support.okta.com/help/Documentation/Knowledge_Article/46749316-On-Premises-Provisioning-Deployment-Guide